# Entity Framework Migrations Integration Tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration, integration-testing

Is there a way to write test for specific versions of the migrations?

Lets say that i have done "add-migration 01 Added column...." -> "08 Deleted column...".
And in my tests i want to see how each and every migration from 01 to 08 is doing.
So, to begin with i want to run all the migrations to the version "01 Added column..." and do a test in that state.
After that i may want to upgrade the database to "05..." and do some testing there. 
And last, i want to upgrade the database all the way, and do some finishing tests.

Is this posible with EF Migrations Code first?

Comment: Are you asking about how to upgrade to specific migration?

Comment: Yes, i want to upgrade to a specific version, and then do some testing on the Model. And then maybe upgrade to a newer version and continue doing some testing. and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have an access to EF right now, so my code could not work, but I hope that it can give you a general direction of what you can do.

You can create a custom database initializer:

```
public sealed class MigrationInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>
{
    private readonly string _targetMigration;

    public MigrationInitializer()
    {
    }

    public MigrationInitializer(string targetMigration)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetMigration))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("targetMigration");
        }

        _targetMigration = targetMigration;
    }

    public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
    {
        var migrationsConfiguration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
        { 
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false 
        };
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(migrationsConfiguration);
        if (_targetMigration == null)
        {
            migrator.Update();  
        }
        else
        {
            migrator.Update(_targetMigration);
        }
    }
}
```

Then force EF to use it in your tests:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MigrationInitializer("MyMigration"));
```

To migrate your database to the latest version you simply use default constructor of `MigrationInitializer` class.

Note that you can perform both upgrading and downgrading of your database using this method.